# How to use getline and extract certain parts of the string c++

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, getline

so i have a text file with contents:

```
title
#comment 1
given
#comment 2
second given
#comment 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#row 1
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
#comment 4
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

and i have used this code:

```
while(getline(fin, str)){


 if(getline(fin, str, '#')){
cout << str << endl;  
}
  else{
cout << str << endl;
  }
 }
```

in order to get and print out each line from the text file from above while extracting every line that begins with  a comment or in this case a '#'. it works fine it prints out everything as should except for the first line that says 'title'. i need that printed out along with everything else but why is it not printing? and is there anything i can do to make sure that it prints along with everything else (besides the comments obviously. i also have to check the title to make sure, for this example, it says 'title'. how do i access the very first part of the string? in order to make an if statement for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ones you call function getline as condition of while, you read a line from file to str. Then, you do not need to call it again. It overwrites the first one. That is why the first line is skipped.

```
if(getline(fin, str) && str == "title"){ // check the first line here 
    do {
        if(str[0] != '#')
            cout << str << endl; // print out if read line is not comment
    } while(getline(fin, str));
}
```

With the code above, you can first check the first line, then read the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(getline(fin, str)) {
  if(getline(fin, str, '#')){
    // ...
```

The first time you call `getline` you get the first line (obviously), then you call `getline` again, reading the second line (again, obviously), and replacing the first line from the buffer.

You're not seeing the first line in the output because you're overwriting it with the second line before printing it.

What I *think* you're trying to do is something like this:

```
while(getline(fin, str)) 
  if(str[0] == '#') 
    cout << "comment: " << str << endl;  
  else
    cout << "data: " << str << endl;
```